# setting development project with mongo database on EC2 cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I would like to create a development project on EC2 cluster. Current design suggest accessing mongo database files stored on EBS volume. If that is possible to run distributed computing and access same files in /data/db/ simultaneously from different nodes?

Comment: Probably... Kind of beats the point of distributed nodes though as that'll be one amazing IO bottle neck.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that mongo will lock access to the data files. Mongo does support replication via replica sets and sharding.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work. You cannot access the same mongodb database files from different processes on different nodes.

The way you use mongoDB in a distributed environment is with replica sets and sharding. In both cases you have mongodb instances running on each node. Replica sets duplicate the same data across all the nodes in the set, for data redundancy and fault tolerance. Sharding allows you to distribute different sets of data on different nodes to provide horizontal scaling. Large production environments use both replica sets and sharding.

Best place to read up on all of this is:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

Comment: do you know if there is a database which will work in this case?